# How to use 2 localhost for single project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I have a project and I need to use 2 port numbers.

Currently, I am working on `localhost:3000` and now I need to use another port number.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following using the port number that you want to use.

```
rails s -p 3001 -b 0.0.0.1
```